# Input button wont extend to width set in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a simple form and in it I have a text box and a button. However I set the width of both to 500px for testing purposes and the text field goes to the correct length but the submit button is 12 pixels less?

[image]

Here's the Code:

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<label>Name</label><br>
<input name="name" placeholder="Your name...">

<br>
<br>

<label>Message</label><br>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>

<br>
<br>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The message box and the name box both are the correct width but the submit button is around 10 pixels less.

**EDIT : SOLUTION**

Thanks to help below, I found the solution, needed to add

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

to the CSS for input & textarea and now it works correctly.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: You're dealing with elements that have default `padding`. Use `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: @Michael_B That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to include padding and borders (that are set by default) into your width. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for more information about box sizing.

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input name="name" placeholder="Your name...">
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the box-sizing of both the boxes to border-box to alter the box model

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<label>Name</label>
<br>
<input name="name" placeholder="Your name...">
<br>
<br>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably mean by "12 pixels less" is the padding of 6px on left and right side of the button (hence the Chrome's developer tools are showing "484x15" for the button.

The padding is, however, a part of the element, so the total size of the button is actually 500px as expected. You can fiddle around with [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) if you want to change this behavior.

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```